# This Nonogram seems a bit...... off

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram

[image]

> Hmm...... Did I miss something? The hidden word has six unique letters anyway......

---

**Hint 1**:

> Uhh...... I should insert something to make this Nonogram normal. But...... What are they?

**Hint 2**:

> Well, something is definitely off...... By...... What? Speaking of the hidden word, it is a name.

**Hint 3**:

> All numbers are already correct so no need to change them. The board however...... Isn't......

<sub>**Addendum**: There is a (very) minor fix to ensure the puzzle "uniquely solvable", adding 1-light-blue clue on the last position of row 5 and the first position of column 21.</sub>

<sup>Click the image for a larger version. The colorblind-friendly version is also available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUZif.png).</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the Nonogram seems off is that

> The grid should actually be 27x27 instead of 21x21.

After a lot of blood, sweat and tears, the actual Nonogram looks like this

> [image]

And yes, I was disappointed too. It doesn't differ much from the one posted by Kruga. But it **does** fulfill the rules of a Nonogram!

As to who this is meant to represent, I'm at a loss. However, I did notice that

> We are given that the hidden name has 6 unique letters. And there are 6 extra columns (and rows) needed to complete the Nonogram. These are columns 3, 5, 8, 15, 19 and 26 which could translate to the letters C, E, H, O, S and Z. Unfortunately, I don't see a name in there that I recognize.

**Edit**

After a strong clue by OP in comments it seems the character's name is

> [SCHEZO](https://www.giantbomb.com/schezo-wegey/3005-24789/). Must admit I hadn't heard of the Puyo Puyo series before. :)

Comment: Terng wbo! Nf lbh unir gur pbeerpg 6 yrggref, V'yy tvir njnl gur anzr: Vg vf gur punenpgre gur vzntr ercerfrag, sebz Chlb Chlb frevrf :)

Comment: @athin Thanks for the hint! Nice puzzle, but quite tough.

Comment: Congratulations! Indeed, I was afraid this one is going to be hard to tackle (I also struggled when tried to re-solve it.) Great solve (and determination) there nevertheless! :D

Answer (score 19):

It's off because

> If you look at just the yellow or red, it's impossible to fit in. There is also some rows whose sum of its clues plus space is bigger than the size of the grid. Therefore I think that clues of the same color does not need an empty space between them.

The solved nonogram

> [image]
>  The green is empty cells. I got stuck on the last bit. I don't think it has a unique solution, unless there is another rule I haven't found.

The puzzle depicts

> athin's profile picture
>  [image]
>  As for the hidden word, I don't known, since "athin" is not 6 letters.

Comment: Good start! Try to find more clues, :)

Comment: The standard for color nonograms is that no empty spaces are needed between blocks of different colors, as there is already a distinct demarcation.

Comment: In the bottom two lines you should have blank spaces between the blue blocks.  The same goes for the top of the puzzle with the light blue squares.  I believe that will make a unique solution, but have not completed the puzzle.  But then your explanation for what is a bit off is incorrect.